# How to convert javascript "Specific object" into "normal object"?

Tags: javascript, object

Don't know how to phrase this differently. Perhaps a view on the code will be self-explanatory:

```
var test = dis.LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLocationAvailability(dis.googleApiClient);
console.log( test );
console.log( typeof test );
```

Outcome is this:

```
LocationAvailability[isLocationAvailable: true]
object
```

Basicaly what I want is to call `test.isLocationAvailable` which returns value, like a normal object.

I could turn this into a string and then peal the result out of it, but that is nasty. If I will have to access different properties with custom length, I'm gona be in trouble.

Comment: normal, what is normal. I used to ask this as well :)

Comment: But the `typeof` says its an object >.<

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is weird, but it actually was stored as a function. Calling `dis.LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLocationAvailability(dis.googleApiClient).isLocationAvailable()` worked.